# Identifying image sequences in EXIF info of photos created by Panasonic cameras

Tags: metadata, panasonic-lumix

My Panasonic GX-800 camera writes the MakerNote tag [0x002b Exif.Panasonic.SequenceNumber](http://www.exiv2.org/tags-panasonic.html) to the EXIF info. When I do exposure bracketing or make a burst of photos, I can get the ordinal number of each photo inside that sequence from this field (i.e., this field has a value of 1 for first photo in the sequence and has a value of 7 for the 7th photo).

It's great to know each photo's ordinal inside its sequence, but which photos belong to the same sequence? I can not find any EXIF field that would tell me this. Is there a way to identify photos that belong to the same sequence based on the EXIF tags of Panasonic cameras?

Comment: Note: I could calculate a sequence ID by subtracting the SequenceNumber from the photo's own ordinal number (e.g., p1120106.jpg with SequenceNumber 2 belongs to the same sequence as p1120107.jpg with SequenceNumber 3, because 1120106 - 2 = 1120107 - 3), but I can not find the photo's own ordinal number in the EXIF info either and some of my photos got renamed thus the number from their original file name is no longer available.

Comment: Doesn't your camera include a Timestamp in the EXIF Info that includes date and time down to hour:minute:second? That, combined with the ordinal referenced in the question, should be enough.

Comment: Yes, there is even an answer suggesting this below. I was hoping to find a cleaner solution, like some dedicated EXIF field I overlooked that identifies the sequence, but if nothing better comes up, I will accept the answer suggesting the date field.

Answer (score 1):

For some use cases you could use time as a fairly strong heuristic. For instance, given a fairly consistent framerate of (say, for simplicity's sake) 1/s, then subtracting the ordinal from `datetimeoriginal` should give you results within a fairly narrow range. This could of course fail if you're shooting really fast bursts in fast sequence.

You could also use this method only as a fallback for the cases where the filename no longer provides the photo's own ordinal number, further reducing the likelihood of errors.